# Ramda remove objects from array based on nested value

Tags: ramda.js

I'm trying to remove an object from an array of objects if a certain value exists in nested data.

The data being returned from the API is shaped like this:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "id": "/db/Shifts/123",
    "applicants": Object {
      "applicants": Array [
        "/db/User/12",
        "/db/User/13",
      ],
  },
  Object {
    "id": "/db/Shifts/456",
    "applicants": Object {
      "applicants": Array [
        "/db/User/12",
        "/db/User/14",
      ],
  },  
  Object {
    "id": "/db/Shifts/789",
    "applicants": Object {
      "applicants": Array [
        "/db/User/13",
        "/db/User/14",
      ],
  },
]
```

Using Ramda, how would I filter out the shifts where User 12 exists in the array of applicants, which would be located at applicants.applicants.

I am not able to flatten the data in this case, the list of applicants for each shift does have to be an array contained in an object.

I tried this:

```
var hasApplied = pathEq(['applicants', 'applicants'], 'db/User/12');
console.log(filter(hasApplied, shifts));
```

But I don't think that is quite right because applicants.applicants is an array, I feed like I need to be feeding it one more function to get into the array of applicants but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `R.pathEq` is resulting in the user ID being compared with each array of IDs for equality, rather than checking whether each array contains the given ID.

You could instead make use of [`R.pathSatisfies`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pathSatisfies) along with [`R.contains`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#contains)

```
const hasApplied = R.pathSatisfies(R.contains('/db/User/12'), ['applicants', 'applicants'])
```